# How to automatically convert a MySQL column to lowercase

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a property that I can add to a column so that it converts its value to lowercase? Instead of doing it for every single value through PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do it through a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that fires on insert or update. Myself, I'd rather just create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html) that has a lower-case version of the column in question. The SQL for the view might look like

```
SELECT ID, LOWER(MY_COLUMN) AS MY_COLUMN_LOWERCASE
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: I've added links for triggers and views.

Comment: excellent, but how do u tell mysql to convert selected column to lowercase?

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

Comment: The one thing that might catch you up here is you'll need to change your code (PHP I believe) to use the view, not query the table anymore.  Another option might be to use the lower() function in your select query from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but don't do it.

If you want exclusively lowercase characters in a column, convert them when you insert (or update) them.

If you need a column to be case insensitive in comparisons, use a case insensitive collation (which are used by default in e.g. utf8 columns)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this?

```
  UPDATE table SET column = LOWER(column)
```