# Postgresql: auto lowercase text while (or before) inserting to a column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to achieve case insensitive uniqueness in a varchar column. But, there is no case insensitive text data type in Postgres. Since original case of text is not important, it will be a good idea to convert all to lowercase/uppercase before inserting in a column with UNIQUE constraint. Also, it will require one INDEX for quick search.

Is there any way in Postgres to manipulate data before insertion?

I looked at this other question: [How to automatically convert a MySQL column to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518673/mysql-column-auto-convert-value-to-lowercase-how-to).
It suggests using triggers on insert/update to lowercase text or to use views with lowercased text. But, none of the suggested methods ensure uniqueness.

Also, since this data will be read/written by various applications, lowercasing data in every individual application is not a good idea.

Comment: None of the current answers will actually lowercase the data before insert, which is what's being asked. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807709/create-a-postgres-rule-or-trigger-to-automatically-convert-a-column-to-lowercase.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't need a case-insensitive data type (although [there is one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html))

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_lower_unique 
   ON your_table (lower(the_column));
```

That way you don't even have to mess around with the original data.

Comment: Verified, it works exactly as I wanted it to. Stores case sensitive data (which was not required, but good to have), but enforces case-insensitive uniqueness.

Comment: This will still let you insert uppercase letters tho, so it shouldn't be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 46):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT your_table_the_column_lowercase_ck
  CHECK (the_column = lower(the_column));
```

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/indexes-unique.html):

> The use of indexes to enforce unique constraints could be considered
>   an implementation detail that should not be accessed directly.

Comment: I used this, because I can let my app handle putting in data in the correct lower-case format, while using the DB for what it's good for - integrity checking.