# Create a Postgres rule or trigger to automatically convert a column to lowercase or uppercase on insert

Tags: postgresql

How would you create a rule in postgres to force lowercase on X column on insert. EG When inserting:

```
INSERT INTO foobar (foo, bar) VALUES ('EXAMPLE', 2);
```

I would want `EXAMPLE` to be lowercased to `example` before persisting.

Comment: Why does part of your rule use `NEW.foo` and the other just `foo`?

Comment: New to postgres and was guessing at a solution. Tried it without the new and still got an error :/

Comment: Does it slow things down significantly if you just let it do that action on every insert?

Comment: Also, `ascii()` only works on the first character in the string.

Comment: @CollinGrady Thanks for the tip on ascii(). So that's a bad way of going about it... I'm not too worried about speed, more important to have everything lowercased in this situation.

Comment: Two things: 1). what version of Postgres, 2). Is the uppercase or lowercase dependent on the input, or is one or the other desired for *all* input? If the latter, a BEFORE INSERT trigger is probably what you're after.

Comment: @bma 1) Version PostgreSQL 9.1.9, 2) Do you think performance would be better if it checked to see if any upper case characters are being used in the "foo" column and if so apply the lower, otherwise skip it ... Or just better to apply to all?

Comment: Obviously there is overhead from checking to see the case of the input, but if you don't need that then converting them *all* to upper or lowercase is fine. If you want to benchmark, trying loading a million rows via trigger with and without the check and you should be able to determine quickly the overhead. My off-the-cuff advice is to apply the upper-or-lowercase function regardless of the case of the input. I didn't see any projected operations-per-second counts, but if you are only expecting dozens per second, I would opt for applying the upper/lower function regardless of input case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [databases](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**This solution has been tested and is working in Postgres 9.1**

I used triggers to solve problem.

Here's the full code so you can paste into postgres and try it out yourself & explanation of how it works below

```
DROP TABLE foobar;
CREATE TABLE foobar (
foo text,
bar int
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lowecase_foo_on_insert() RETURNS trigger AS $lowecase_foo_on_insert$
    BEGIN        
        NEW.foo = LOWER(NEW.foo);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$lowecase_foo_on_insert$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER lowecase_foo_on_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON foobar
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lowecase_foo_on_insert();

INSERT INTO foobar (foo, bar) VALUES ('LOWERCASE ME', 1);

SELECT * FROM foobar; //result 'lowercase me'
```

Create our demo table:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    foo text,
    bar int
);
```

Create function that converts (foo) to lowercase:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lowecase_foo_on_insert() RETURNS trigger AS $lowecase_foo_on_insert$
    BEGIN        
        NEW.foo = LOWER(NEW.foo);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$lowecase_foo_on_insert$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Create a trigger that executes code to lowercase foo before insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lowecase_foo_on_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON foobar
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lowecase_foo_on_insert();
```

And now to test our work:

```
INSERT INTO foobar (foo, bar) VALUES ('LOWERCASE ME', 1);
SELECT * FROM foobar;
```

Result is that the only row in column foo is now set to 'lowercase me'

Comment: Is it possible to make `lower_foo_on_insert()` dynamic? e.g., `lower_on_insert('foo')`

Answer (score 1):

Updated after more info: Try using a trigger instead to force-lowercase the field after an insert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I'm still not able to get it to work. That rule above never actually worked. I updated the post a bit with the error I'm currently getting when I try to insert anything: ERROR: infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "foobar"

Comment: Ah. That would've been helpful info ;)

Comment: Yeah :/ The rule was not working before, I couldn't even get it to accept it until you suggested dropping the WHERE statement. So I just started getting that new error. Progress anyway ;)