# Yii - insert to Postgres all in uppercase

Tags: postgresql, yii, insert, uppercase

how to insert data to db with form generated by gii with additional option, e.g. UPPER.

Generally I'd like do some sql insert commands (`save()` methods) like

```
INSERT INTO table(column_name) VALUES(UPPER(column_value))
```

on Postgres db.

Can I (if - how) do this in my controller code, in `actionCreate` method?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: did you find what you where looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the tamplate that gii is using to generate exactly what you want by altering file in :

\protected\extensions\giix-core\giixCrud\templates\default
\protected\extensions\giix-core\giixModel\templates

you can even extend GxActiveRecord and GxController in giix-component to extend from a class that you have defined, to implement default scopes and beforeSaves and other stuff.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to create a trigger on postgres instead of change every save method on your code.

[This answer could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18939742/4056187).