Case sensitive column in PostgreSQL
I use PostgreSQL 13.15 version and i don't understand how to make column case insensitive.
This is table languages and column code is primary key. I want to make it case insensitive.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.languages
(
    code character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT languages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (code)
);


I want to prevent second insert because i already have a code 'eng'
INSERT INTO public.languages(code, name) VALUES ('eng', 'English');
INSERT INTO public.languages(code, name) VALUES ('ENG', 'English');

Currently it successfully added second insert and it's wrong because i already have code 'eng' and i don't want to have duplications 'ENG' or 'Eng' . If i'm not mistaking it can be done by using Collation but i'm not sure if it's a correct way. In pgAdmin 4 i didn't find anything in properties on column


Change the collation to a case-insensitive one

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC.

This (older) suggestion creates an index where the row is converted to a lowercase. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046836/319826

You have got a few choices:

Use the citext extension:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext SCHEMA public;
ALTER TABLE public.languages ALTER code TYPE citext;


Use a case insensitive ICU collation:
CREATE COLLATION und_ci (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   DETERMINISTIC = FALSE,
   LOCALE = 'und@colStrength=secondary'
);

ALTER TABLE public.languages ALTER code TYPE character varying(10) COLLATE und_ci;

See the ICU documentation for how to define ICU collations.

Use a custom unique index instead of the primary key:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON public.languages (lower(code));




I tested by just using a citext column as primary key, and there is no need for the collation and the unique index. Am I missing something?

Can you tell me please what is this 'und@colStrength=secondary' ? What is 'und@colStrength' and why it 'secondary'

@Romillion I added a link to the ICU documentation.

@FlorianKlein My three points are alternatives. You need to pick only one of them.

There is no default case-insensitive collation for postgress but you can use extensions like https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html
